# How to render partial view using JQuery depending on True or false?

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I have an Error Box which I use on almost all of my pages and I've started to try and put in in a partial view so I can just call the box if the correct result is returned. For example, I have JQuery which will validate a text box to check for a phone number, if it isn't in the correct format then a boolean will be returned as false. At this point I would like to render the partial view and simultaneously change the content of the error box as it is used for many validation checks.

How can I do this?

JQuery:

```
 <script>
        $('#ContactUsButton').click(function () {
            var PhoneNum = $('#ContactUsPhoneNumTxt').val();
            var regex = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/;
            var rt = false;
            if (!regex.test(PhoneNum)) {
                rt = false;
                $("#ErrorBoxText").html("Error : Incorrect data type in Phone Number");
            }
            else {
                rt = true;
            }

            //Code which will call partial view if RT is false and change the content of the div

            return rt;
        })
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
     <div id="RenderErrorBoxPartial">
                    @Html.Partial("_ErrorBox")
                </div>
```

Partial:

```
<div id="ErrorBox" hidden>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
        <p id="ErrorBoxText"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, "hidden" is not a standard HTML attribute. Are you using bootstrap bro?

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap

Comment: Please check my answer :0

Answer (score 0):

I made a small modification on your error HTML. Can you please try to use this code?

```
    <div id="ErrorBox" class="hidden">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
            <p id="ErrorBoxText"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ContactUsButton').click(function () {
            var PhoneNum = $('#ContactUsPhoneNumTxt').val(),
                regex = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/,
                rt = false,
                errorTextbox = $("#ErrorBoxText");

            if (!regex.test(PhoneNum)) {
                errorTextbox.text("Error : Incorrect data type in Phone Number")
                                  .removeClass("hidden");
            }
            else {
                errorTextbox.text("")
                            .addClass("hidden");

                rt = true;
            }

            //Code which will call partial view if RT is false and change the content of the div

            return rt;
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.load` method to load your `partialview` at any case as below

```
$('#ContactUsButton').click(function () {
      var PhoneNum = $('#ContactUsPhoneNumTxt').val();
      var regex = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/;
      var rt = false;
      if (!regex.test(PhoneNum)) {
           $("#ErrorBoxText").html("Error : Incorrect data type in Phone Number");
      }
      else {
           $("#RenderErrorBoxPartial").load("/ControllerName/LoadPartial",function(){
                   //In case you have to do anything once load it complete
           })
      }
})
```

Add one `actionresult` in controller which returns the `partialView`

```
public ActionResult LoadPartial()
{
     return PartialView("_YourPartialViewName");
}
```

> Note: You don't need to assign any bool variable or return anything here to load
>   `partialview`. Just load it directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mvc, you could use Ajax [Link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): Jquery:

```
var ajaxUrl = '@Url.action("ActionName", "controller")';
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxUrl,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function (result) {
    $('#RenderErrorBoxPartial').empty().append(result);
    $('#ErrorBoxText').html("Error : Incorrect data type in Phone Number"); //to make sure it sets the text

  },
  error: function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Server side:

```
Public ActionResult ActionName () {
  return View("_ErrorBox");
}
```